# What is the second argument in ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String path, Class<?> clazz)

Tags: xml, spring

Please help me understand Javadocs of this method. How does the second argument affect the context returned?

> This is a convenience method to load class path resources relative to
>   a given Class. For full flexibility, consider using a
>   GenericApplicationContext with an XmlBeanDefinitionReader and a
>   ClassPathResource argument.

Answer (score 0):

`Class<?>` is a generic type using an unbound wildcard. it means "`Class<Foo>` for some type of Foo". **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** constructor parameter clazz takes the class to load resources with (basis for the given paths).

```
/**
 * Create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, loading the definitions
 * from the given XML file and automatically refreshing the context.
 * <p>This is a convenience method to load class path resources relative to a
 * given Class. For full flexibility, consider using a GenericApplicationContext
 * with an XmlBeanDefinitionReader and a ClassPathResource argument.
 * @param path relative (or absolute) path within the class path
 * @param clazz the class to load resources with (basis for the given paths)
 * @throws BeansException if context creation failed
 * @see org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource#ClassPathResource(String, Class)
 * @see org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext
 * @see org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
 */
public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String path, Class clazz) throws BeansException {
    this(new String[] {path}, clazz);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for further elaboration on this javadoc. What kinds of resources does this mean in context of ClasspathXmlApplicationContext? What does "relative to a given class" mean here? Please elaborate, preferably, with an example or reference to some documentation.

Thank you for your reply!